# how can I tell whether capsule use is coming from natural language discovery

Tags: bixby

How can I tell what, if any, usage of my capsule is coming from discovery by subscribing to natural language categories?

https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/reference/ref-topics/categories

Additional comment: this would be useful both for analytics and to customize user experience depending on source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This functionality is not currently available but I would recommend that you file a feature request on the [community forum](https://support.bixbydevelopers.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/360000183273-Feature-Requests).

This forum is open to other Bixby developers who can upvote it, leading to more visibility within the community and with the Product Management team.